# using xsd attributes in another xsd as tag/tag-parameters

Tags: xsd

I wanted to know if it is possible or not:

a.xsd :

```
<attribute name="aa" type="String">
```

b.xsd

```
<element name="bb" aa="pan" type="string"/>
```

or

```
<aa name="pan" type="string">
```

basically i am trying to find out if we can use the xsd attributes inside another xsd as tags or tag-parameters.

i am new to this xsd world if it is wrong use-case then also please post your views.

Answer (score 0):

I am not clear on what you are trying to accomplish, but the xsd:element element has a set of recognized attributes.  It won't do you any good to try to make up attributes to add to it.